# Unable to instantiate any file during oracle xe installation

Tags: oracle

I am trying to install Oracle XE 11g on windows 7,32 bit machine.

The set up process goes fine until the step where the Oracle asks for password setup. Later when the installation starts, I get a pop up that says cannot instantiate the listener.ora file. I say OK, and then try to continue. But, then again, the another pop up says tnsnames.ora cannot be instantiated. This message continues with different file names unable to be instantiated. And finally the set up terminates

Any help in this would be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Are you using an administrator account? Maybe it can't create the directory for those files to be created under. The installer log files might provide more useful information.

Comment: yes, it doesn't sound like you have admin on that pc. If you're at work best contact IT support!

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the response.I checked the user account settings and it says that my account is an administrator account. Also , I tried installing again with the UAC turned off,but, ended with the same problem as stated above. Is there anything else I can do?

Comment: Hi,found the solution a couple of days ago, but, had forgotten to comment back. The problem was with the absence of host name and host address in the hosts file. Once entered , the installation took place successfully

Answer (score 0):

I too faced the same issue, finally below are the reason for my issue

1. I did not have full permission to that folder where I am installing Oracle
2. Make sure the command prompt opened in Admin mode